# Programa em C para concatenar strings não executa corretamente

Tags: c, string, funções, char

## include

```
int main(){

    void concatenarStrings(char string1[], int t1,
                           char string2[], int t2,
                           char string3[]);

    char palavra1[]={'p','a','o','c','o','m'};
    char palavra2[]={'m','o','r','t','a','d','e','l','a'};
    char novaPalavra[16];

    concatenarStrings(palavra1,6,palavra2,9,novaPalavra);

    int i;
    for(int i = 0;i < 1;++i){
        printf("%c",novaPalavra[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}

void concatenarStrings(char string1[], int t1,
                       char string2[], int t2,
                       char string3[]){
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < t1; ++i){
        string3[i] = string1[i];
}
    for(j = 0; j < t2; ++j){
        string3[t1 + j] = string2[j];

    }                       
}
```

Meu código acima compila corretamente no DEV C++,não apresenta nenhum erro. É um código para concatenar as strings palavra1 e palavra2,porém sempre quando executo ele,ao invés de formar a palavra pao com mortadela,ele exibe somente a palavra p.
Não consigo ver onde está o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco, o problema é o `for` no seu `main`. Declare-o assim:

```
//Você já declarou a variável i, então pode usá-la sem declará-la novamente
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
```

Quando for chamar um `for`, prefira usar `variável++`, assim ela só será incrementada depois da primeira iteração.

Comment: Muito obrigado.